# What is the best way to design and changing GTK interface?

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, glade, gtk3

I am designing a python program using GTK3 and Glade. It requires changing the interface depending on what the user is needing to build.

The first interface is something like:

```
____________________________________________________
| Label one | Text entry one |  Save object button |
| Label two | Text entry two |                     |
____________________________________________________
```

which is in a top level window inside a Gtk.Box() set to vertical with a Gtk.Grid() as the labels and text entries in one side of the box and the save Save object button on the section of the box. (my interface in reality is much more complicated that this with many more labels, text entries, toggle buttons, comboboxes, etc within the table). If you want to see it, it is at http://sourceforge.net/projects/createlauncher.

If the user needs to build another object, it would look like:

```
________________________________________________________
| Label three | Text entry three |  Save object button |
| Label four  | Text entry four  |                     |
________________________________________________________
```

What are some suggestions on how to implement the change?

I've thought of keeping track of label one-two and entry one-two, and hiding them and showing the others but it messes with the formating. I have messed around with deleting each widget and rebuilding if needing to switch back. It is a lot of work. Since I'm using Glade, it is hard to create a separate "area" as I thought about deleting the Gtk.Box() and remaking it for the other interface needs, but that seems prohibitive using Glade.

I'm open to any and all options.

Answer (score 1):

Composite custom widgets?

```
class ObjectOneSettings(Gtk.Grid):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Grid.__init__(self)
        self.label_one = Gtk.Label('Label One')
        self.label_two = Gtk.Label('Label Two')
        self.entry_one = Gtk.Entry()
        self.entry_two = Gtk.Entry()
        self.attach(self.label_one, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.attach(self.label_two, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.attach(self.entry_one, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.attach(self.entry_two, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Then you can destroy your `ObjectOneSettings` widget and replace it with an `ObjectTwoSettings` widget when you need to change the window.

Comment: This is one way I was thinking about (I was thinking function rather than class, but same idea) and was worried that destroying the Grid might not delete the child widgets resulting in a large memory footprint with repeated interface switches. I was also thinking about doing a grid1.show()/grid2.hide() game, too inside another Gtk.Box container with two grid with one showing and the other hiding and switching between the two (there is actually a third state as well, but I'll add that once I decide on the overall direction). Thanks as it helps me think I'm not thinking "stupidly."

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a bit of a hack, but you could use a notebook with hidden tabs and border.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Glade, I can think of two approaches.

The first one is to change the label of the Gtk.Label and the Gtk.Entry dynamically in your python code depending on what you need.

The second one is to create a separate Gtk.Box in Glade that is not inside the main window and add it when you need it (first remove the other one from the window). This would look like this:

[image: glade with separate box]